# C# Custom Canvas class, ActualHeight/Width are always 0

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I want to implement class that draw grid on `Canvas`, but problem is that `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` are set to 0.

[image]
Canvas is all this gray area.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'm newbie in C#. Thanks!

```
class ImageGrid : Canvas
{
    private double GridSize = 50;

    public ImageGrid()
    {
        Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
    }

    public void  DrawGrid()
    {

        Children.Clear();

        #region Draw image
        // TODO - Draw image
        #endregion

        #region Draw grid

        for ( double x = 0; x < ActualWidth; x+=GridSize )
        {
            Line line = new Line();
            line.X1 = x;
            line.X2 = x;
            line.Y1 = 0;
            line.Y2 = ActualWidth;              // Why 0 ?
            line.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            line.StrokeThickness = 1;
            Children.Add(line);
        }

        for ( double y = 0; y < ActualHeight; y += GridSize )
        {
            Line line = new Line();
            line.X1 = 0;
            line.X2 = ActualHeight;             // Why 0 ?
            line.Y1 = y;
            line.Y2 = y;
            line.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            line.StrokeThickness = 1;
            Children.Add(line);
        }

        #endregion

    }

}
```

ImageGrid call:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ImageGrid ig = new ImageGrid();
        Grid.Children.Add(ig);
        ig.DrawGrid();
    }
}
```

Comment: When is DrawGrid being called? If you are checking it before the layout pass then the value would be 0.

Comment: @Slowbrochacho Have edited, take a look.

Comment: You probably need to let the Grid render before you can call `.ActualHeight` and `.ActualWidth`, since they are values determined based on the actual rendered size of the Canvas.

Comment: @Rachel But I call DrawGrid after I add ImageGrid to Grid

Comment: @MatjažMav Yes, but you haven't given it a change to render yet, so the size is still whatever the default is, which is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the layout pass before getting the ActualHeight/Width, try calling ig.DrawGrid in the Loaded handler.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ImageGrid ig = new ImageGrid();
        Grid.Children.Add(ig);
        ig.Loaded += ImageGrid_Loaded;
       
    }
    void ImageGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         ig.DrawGrid();
    }
}
```

Note from [FrameWorkElement.ActualHeight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> This property is a calculated value based on other height inputs, and the layout system. The value is set by the layout system itself, based on an actual rendering pass, and may therefore lag slightly behind the set value of properties such as Height that are the basis of the input change.
>
> Because ActualHeight is a calculated value, you should be aware that there could be multiple or incremental reported changes to it as a result of various operations by the layout system. The layout system may be calculating required measure space for child elements, constraints by the parent element, and so on.

Comment: Thank you! Do you maybe know what is handler name for "on resize"

Comment: Well there is a SizeChanged event you can set the handler name your self. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx